# resizing window html

Tags: html, resize

I'm trying to build a simple html page which include some text paragraph, during resizing the window I want the text to appear under each other in order not to be hidden by the window.
 for example,

the text is

AAAABBBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGG.

and after resizing the window I want it to appear something like

AAAABBBBBCCC
 CDDDDEEEEFFF
   FGGGG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [word-wrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) property and set it to `break-word`. ex,

```
<p style="word-wrap: break-word">AAAABBBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGG</p>
```